# Fit img inside flex-box divs

Tags: css, flexbox

I have spent 2 hours trying to solve this simple problem. I need a tall img to fit inside a div. This div must resize with the browser height. But it always overflows, not matter what I try. There is some text below the img that must appear.

```
<html style="height: 100%">
  <body style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden; margin: 0">
    <div id="div-1" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; height:100%">
      <div id="div-2" style="min-height:0px;" >
          <div id="div-3" style="min-height:0px;" >
              <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465680949814-1ed23ecb963f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"
                   style="max-width:100%; max-height:100%; object-fit: contain"/>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div style="height:30px">This text should be displayed below the image</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

https://codepen.io/orobert91/pen/MWwZLGV

When inspecting elements, you can see that the body, `div-1` and `div-2` have the right height, but `div-3` overflows.

Solutions over the Internet suggest to put max-width, max-height, object-fit to the img, also some suggest to wrap the img inside a block div, which I did, but it does not work in my case. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: `min-height: 0;` to div2 and remove body margin

Comment: It does work in this case, thank you. But it does not work if I further wrap div-2 inside another div (example updated). My real world example has nested divs.

Comment: height: 100%; to div3

Comment: That was it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you set an img, you can modify it to the div it's inside

if you set in your css

```
img {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#div-2 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

the img will be the full size of the div and you can then just resize and move around the div and the img will stay the full size of the div

Comment: I can't set a fixed height to div-2, it must stay responsive

Comment: does it not work if you just set a percentage with the img and leave div-2 as it is? Should automatically resize with the page when div-2 resizes

Answer (score 0):

Not the best, but it works

```html
<html style="height: 100%">
  <body style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden">
    <div id="div-1" style="display: flex; flex-direction: column; align-content: stretch; height:100%">
      <div id="div-2" style="flex: 1 1 auto;  overflow: hidden">
          <img src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1465680949814-1ed23ecb963f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&w=1000&q=80"
               style="object-fit: contain"/>
      </div>
      <div style="flex: 0 1 auto; min-height: 30px">This text should be displayed.</div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't know the height of the text div in advance.

Comment: Just edited. It's better now.